# Should I have to install django every time I want to access my project?

Tags: django

Please help how to access the django project when I quit the command prompt it just disappears and cannot locate it yet.  Should I have to install django every time I want to access my project? How can I do it because it keeps asking me django-admin is not an internal command

Comment: Please do *not* use tricks to bypass the quality filters.

Answer (score 0):

This will make Django's code importable, and will also make the `django-admin` utility command available. In other words, you're all set!

```
$ python -m pip install -e django/
```

Please see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/install/ for further information.